# Error when declaring a js variable/ Object (Uncaught DOMException)

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

My script runs into the error:

> Uncaught DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

The script should check, if the database is filled. If not fill the database with initial values. After that display the values in inputfields.
The error occures at  `var data = marmaInfo.result`

```
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB
var db;
    // Open (or create) the database
    var open = indexedDB.open("marmaDB", 1);
    console.log("open Db ...");

    // Create the schema
    console.log("creating schema ...");
    open.onupgradeneeded = function() {
        db = open.result;
        var store = db.createObjectStore("marmasStore", {keyPath: "id"});
    store.createIndex('sanskrit', 'sanskrit', { unique: false });
      };

    function getObjectStore(store_name, mode) {
        var tx = db.transaction(store_name, mode);
        return tx.objectStore(store_name);
    }

    open.onsuccess = function() {
        console.log("open DB DONE");
        // Start a new transaction
        db = open.result;
        store = getObjectStore("marmasStore", 'readwrite');
        //var tx = db.transaction("marmasStore", "readwrite");
        //var store = tx.objectStore("marmasStore");
        //var index = store.index("NameIndex");

        // Initial data
        const initialMarmaData = [
            { id: "ani_ll", sanskrit: "ani"},
        ];

        // Store values
        // initial DB filling 
        
        var key = $('#marmaID').val();
        console.log("key " + key );
        var marmaInfo = store.get(key);
        //marmaInfo.onsuccess = function(evt) {
        var data = marmaInfo.result  //###### ERROR at this line ######
        if (data.sanskrit == 0){
            console.log("record " + key + ":", record);
            console.log("initial filling DB ...");
            var store = getObjectStore("marmasStore", 'readwrite');
            initialMarmaData.forEach((marma) => {
                var request = store.put(marma);
                request.onsuccess = (event) => {
                    console.log(event.target.result + " initial filling DB DONE");
                };
            });
        }
        //}
        //fill the form with DB values
        console.log("filling form ...");
        document.getElementById('sanskrit').value = data.sanskrit;
        console.log("filling form DONE");
        
      }
```

Comment: Have you checked the value provided from `store.get(key)`?

Comment: if I put this `console.log( marmaInfo );` I get 
IDBRequest { source: IDBObjectStore, transaction: IDBTransaction, readyState: "pending", onsuccess: null, onerror: null }
[...]
result: Object { id: "ani_la", sanskrit: "ani", … }
Which looks good, so the .result is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to wait for the result of `getKey` to return. This code was taken from mdn web docs:

```
let request = store.getKey(IDBKeyRange(yesterday, today));
  request.onsuccess = (event) => {
    let when = event.target.result;
    alert(`The 1st activity in last 24 hours was occurred at ${when}`);
  };
```

The `.onsuccess` call essentially waits for the `getKey` function to return, therefor defining the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here, if `onsuccess` is called before `onupgradeneeded`, your variable `store` has not been instantiated even if you give it a value. Maybe is it a problem in your case.

However you should try to use `let` and `const` if possible, for better variable's scope usage

Comment: I now tried to declare var store outside of .onupgradeneeded. it did not make a difference.

Comment: If this was the case the error would point to the line `var marmaInfo = store.get(key);`

Answer (score 0):

Most definitely not the best solution. I arrived there with trial and error, but it works:
(Hints are still apriciated.)

```
var store;
var data;
```

[...]

```
open.onsuccess = function() {
console.log("open DB DONE");
// Start a new transaction
db = open.result;
store = getObjectStore("marmasStore", 'readwrite');
//var tx = db.transaction("marmasStore", "readwrite");
//var store = tx.objectStore("marmasStore");

// Initial data
const initialMarmaData = [
    { id: "ani_ll", sanskrit: "ani" },
];
// Store values
// initial DB filling 
var key = $('#marmaID').val();
console.log("key " + key );
store = getObjectStore("marmasStore", 'readwrite');

var marmaInfo = store.get(key);
marmaInfo.onsuccess = function(evt) {
    console.log(key + " FOUND");
    var record = evt.target.result;
    console.log("record:", record);
    if (typeof record == 'undefined') {
        displayActionFailure("No matching record found");
        return;
    }
    // Update the data
    //new values
    console.log("updating " + key + " ...");
    data = marmaInfo.result
    if (data.sanskrit == 0 ){
        console.log("record " + key + ":", record);
        console.log("initial filling DB ...");
        initialMarmaData.forEach((marma) => {
        var request = store.put(marma);
        request.onsuccess = (event) => {
            console.log(event.target.result + " initial filling DB DONE");
        };
    });
    }
    document.getElementById('sanskrit').value = data.localisation;
}
```